# DatePicker gives Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker' in full view but NOT in Modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In case the title gets cut off, I am receiving the following error:
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

The datepicker works fine in a Modal form returned as a PartialView, but it throws that error when trying to use it in a full View outside of a Modal/PartialView.

Bundle.Config:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"
                ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-theme*",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.structre.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.css"

            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/themes/base/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/*.css"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/datepickers/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css"
            ));
    }
```

Admin Layout (Where the form should fall under):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Boxer Puppy Dogs Admin</title>

@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script> 
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@ 

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/themes/base/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/datepickers/css")
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Main Layout (to keep things relatively consistent)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Boxer Puppy Dogs</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

@*<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@


@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/themes/base/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/datepickers/css")
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Modal Partial View:

```
@model BoxerPuppyDogs.Models.ManageLitters.LitterViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>

@Html.BeginForm("SaveNewLitter", "ManageLitter", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "newLitterForm" })
{
<div class="modal fade" id="NewLitterDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="RemoveModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Litter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="DialogPlaceHolder">
                    @Html.Partial("_NewLitterFormFields", Model)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
}
```

Full View version:

```
    @model BoxerPuppyDogs.Models.ManageLitters.LitterViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Litter";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @Html.BeginForm("SaveNewLitter", "ManageLitter", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "newLitterForm" })
        {

        @Html.Partial("_NewLitterFormFields", Model)
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>

    }
</div>
```

Both the Modal and Full view call this Partial:

```
    @model BoxerPuppyDogs.Models.ManageLitters.LitterViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LitterDOB").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LitterDOB)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LitterDOB, String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.LitterDOB), new { id = "LitterDOB", @class = "datepicker" })
</div>
```

I originally tried using EditorFor and creating a custom template for this, but that proved obnoxious and I only need this on one control so it's not really necessary at this point.

There's got to be some difference between the Modal and View that call the Partial, but I can't see it.

Comment: You've provided a lot of code. Could you narrow it down to the relevant bits?

Comment: Either narrow it down to the problem, or even better give use also a link to jsfiddle.net

Comment: The problem is I don't know what the problem is to be able to narrow it down further.

I know two things: 

To get the modal to work I have to include the ` <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>` or the datepicker doesn't work on the modal.

And on the full view even including the script it still doesn't work. Which is strange because I include the script (.js vs .min.js) in the bundle I render. So, I'm surprised it needs it on the modal at all.

Comment: You need jquery and jquery ui in both cases. You're missing either hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in the head section of the Layout instead of at the bottom of the Body section.